# How to create a gif image with C#

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi, gif

I want to create a gif file with several frames.
I want to use the Method which Microsoft support--[Image.SaveAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dsyxs70s.aspx)

But I don't know how to set the [EncoderParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hwkztaft.aspx) Paramater to make up a gif file.

I can't find documents to refer. So how to create a gif file with `Image.SaveAdd`

Answer (score 6):

Probably, too late to be useful for the original poster, but I managed to create a proper gif using just System.Drawing. The code below is based on jschroedl's answer, but also sets the frame delays and number of animation loops.

```
// Gdi+ constants absent from System.Drawing.
const int PropertyTagFrameDelay = 0x5100;
const int PropertyTagLoopCount = 0x5101;
const short PropertyTagTypeLong = 4;
const short PropertyTagTypeShort = 3;

const inr UintBytes = 4;

//...

var gifEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Gif);
// Params of the first frame.
var encoderParams1 = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParams1.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
// Params of other frames.
var encoderParamsN = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParamsN.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionTime);            
// Params for the finalizing call.
var encoderParamsFlush = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParamsFlush.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);

// PropertyItem for the frame delay (apparently, no other way to create a fresh instance).
var frameDelay = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
frameDelay.Id = PropertyTagFrameDelay;
frameDelay.Type = PropertyTagTypeLong;
// Length of the value in bytes.
frameDelay.Len = Bitmaps.Count * UintBytes;
// The value is an array of 4-byte entries: one per frame.
// Every entry is the frame delay in 1/100-s of a second, in little endian.
frameDelay.Value = new byte[Bitmaps.Count * UintBytes];
// E.g., here, we're setting the delay of every frame to 1 second.
var frameDelayBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)100);
for (int j = 0; j < Bitmaps.Count; ++j)
    Array.Copy(frameDelayBytes, 0, frameDelay.Value, j * UintBytes, UintBytes);

// PropertyItem for the number of animation loops.
var loopPropertyItem = (PropertyItem)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(PropertyItem));
loopPropertyItem.Id = PropertyTagLoopCount;
loopPropertyItem.Type = PropertyTagTypeShort;
loopPropertyItem.Len = 1;
// 0 means to animate forever.
loopPropertyItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)0);

using (var stream = new FileStream("animation.gif", FileMode.Create))
{
    bool first = true;
    Bitmap firstBitmap = null;
    // Bitmaps is a collection of Bitmap instances that'll become gif frames.
    foreach (var bitmap in Bitmaps)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            firstBitmap = bitmap;
            firstBitmap.SetPropertyItem(frameDelay);
            firstBitmap.SetPropertyItem(loopPropertyItem);
            firstBitmap.Save(stream, gifEncoder, encoderParams1);
            first = false;
        }
        else
        {
            firstBitmap.SaveAdd(bitmap, encoderParamsN);
        }
    }
    firstBitmap.SaveAdd(encoderParamsFlush);
}

// ...

private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, this seems to work well. I wrapped your code into a class definition and added a test procedure for it as a static. Use: AnimatedGif.TestFlickering()

Comment: One change I had to make involved the looping property. It turns out that if you perform SetPropertyItem(loopPropertyItem) with value 0, the GIF will spin endlessly, as intended. But when this value is set to 1, the result will be a GIF that loops 1x (executed *twice* !). The only way to let the GIF not loop  (execute once !) is *not setting* the loop property. So I included a test.

Answer (score 2):

I had success with these parameters. img1,2,3,4... are the images I want to combine.

```
ULONG parameterValue;

EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
encoderParameters.Count = 1;

encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderSaveFlag;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &parameterValue;

// Save the first frame
parameterValue = EncoderValueMultiFrame;
rc = img1->Save(L"Output.gif", &encoderClsid, &encoderParameters);
assert(rc == Ok);

// Add the second frame
parameterValue = EncoderValueFrameDimensionTime;
rc = img1->SaveAdd(img2, &encoderParameters);
assert(rc == Ok);

// etc...adding frames  img3,4,5...

// Done...
parameterValue = EncoderValueFlush;
rc = img1->SaveAdd(&encoderParameters);
assert(rc == Ok);
```

Edit: I just realized that you asked for C# and I have C++ code. Hopefully the parameters still apply.

Comment: While this snippet does create a multi-frame gif, it does not set the frame delay and number of animation loops. I'll post my code (that does it) in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want create gif with many picture you can use [ngif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngif/). see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET)

```
//you should replace filepath
String [] imageFilePaths = new String[]{"c:\\01.png","c:\\02.png","c:\\03.png"}; 
String outputFilePath = "c:\\test.gif";
AnimatedGifEncoder e = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
e.Start( outputFilePath );
e.SetDelay(500);
//-1:no repeat,0:always repeat
e.SetRepeat(0);
for (int i = 0, count = imageFilePaths.Length; i < count; i++ ) 
{
 e.AddFrame( Image.FromFile( imageFilePaths[i] ) );
}
e.Finish();
/* extract Gif */
string outputPath = "c:\\";
GifDecoder gifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
gifDecoder.Read( "c:\\test.gif" );
for ( int i = 0, count = gifDecoder.GetFrameCount(); i < count; i++ ) 
{
 Image frame = gifDecoder.GetFrame( i ); // frame i
 frame.Save( outputPath + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() 
                       + ".png", ImageFormat.Png );
}
```

Comment: I know this demo.But I want to use the Image.SaveAdd method